# "Back" button in supportActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back

how to I get that little back-option when a user clicks on the text on the supportActionBar?
I'm wondering for quite a while and I did not find something that works.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: where should I put this? which is the best place?

Comment: read Adding Up Navigation @ http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html and look at figure1

Comment: if in fragment then use `getActivity().getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragments use

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In activity just

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

To change the title to parent category or fragment if using them :

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString("some title"));
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString("some title"));
```